# Missing modversions.h

Tags: kernel, compiling, make

I`m trying to compile a program, which was actually designed for Linux OS based on kernel 2.4. 
When I run the make command, I get the following error

```
/lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/modversions.h: No such file or directory
```

So I tried to locate the file modversions.h manually by running the command

```
sudo find / modversions.h
```

but I could not find any.

I tried the following

```
cd /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/linux
make update-modverfile
```

but got the following error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `update-modverfile'.  Stop.
```

I also googled about this missing file and it looks to me like this is a common issue with many applications designed for older kernels, so what possibly I could do to fix this issue.

Please to provide your suggestions.

> ### Other Informations
>
> OS: Ubuntu 12.04 
>   Kernel Version: 3.8.0-29 
>   Program I`m trying to compile:[AODV-UU](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aodvuu/)

Comment: "sudo find / modversions.h" this is wrong me thinks. You need to tell find to also echo the result so it needs to be `sudo find / -name modversions.h -print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu's package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=modversions.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise-updates&arch=any), the file you are looking for is part of the package **linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic**. Its full path, according to that package's 
[file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/amd64/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/filelist), is

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/config/modversions.h
```

Comment: I wonder if the Makefile is looking in /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/linux when it is actually, as drc points out, in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/config. I suggest you check the Makefile for the program you are trying to compile. Perhaps there is a variable you can declare to specify where to look; i.e. in config and not linux. Or perhaps you can simply edit the Makefile.

Comment: drc thanks for the reply, I`m relatively new to programming in Linux, Package Search is really helpful

Comment: I didn't have one until I installed the linux-headers package (using Raspbian).  Now  I see /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-6-rpi2/include/config/modversions.h.  But the error message says it's looking for a modversions.h in a linux dir, which I still don't have (by locate).  I wonder if this is old, I'm trying to compile something from 2006, maybe it's all different now.