# Missing asm/types.h file

Tags: kernel, make

I have been trying to compile a very old program actual meant for Kernel

I previously had an issue [Missing Modversions.h](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389245/missing-modversions-h) which is solved now, but there is another issue.

```
In file included from /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/types.h:5:0,
             from /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/list.h:4,
             from /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/linux/module.h:9,
             from kaodv-mod.c:30:
/lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:23: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [kaodv-mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vm1/aodv-12-12-13/lnx'
make: *** [kaodv] Error 2
```

The file /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h is a linux header file, I don`t understand how such an error could occur.

### Other Informations

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Kernel Version: 3.8.0-29
Program I`m trying to compile:[AODV-UU][2]
```

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 4):

This file has been moved. In your Kernel it will be at `include/uapi/asm-generic/types.h`

### Solution

- Update the reference in `types.h` but I'm not sure if it is possible.

or

- Compile this program against it's supported Kernel version, if you have that info.

Comment: I did find asm-generic/types.h but is it okay to edit the kernel header file /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h ?

Comment: How can I update it? I am not sur to understan

Comment: Add path to gcc include with key -I. Foe example -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic/include/uapi

Answer (score 2):

Set your `ARCH` environment variable in terminal to `x86`: `export ARCH=x86`

or

add the line `export ARCH=x86` to the Makefile

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compile a USB WiFi adapter driver whose `Makefile` I was modifying to include riscv64 for the RISC-V VisionFive 2 with Debian, I ran into what appears to be the same error.

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ make
make ARCH=riscv64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build M=/home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-9) 12.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Debian 12.2.0-10) 12.2.0
  CC [M]  /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/types.h:6,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/basic_types.h:75,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/drv_types.h:26,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/uapi/linux/types.h:5:10: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <asm/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:254: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/Makefile:1876: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2410: modules] Error 2
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$
```

I made a quick change in the `types.h` file to use `asm-generic/types.h` and ran into another include directive also using the `asm` directory rather than `asm-generic`.

So I reverted the change I had made and took a different tack. I created a symbolic link named `asm` to the directory `asm-generic`.

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/uapi
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/uapi$ ls
Kbuild  asm-generic  drm  linux  misc  mtd  rdma  scsi  sound  video  xen
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/uapi$ sudo ln -s ./asm-generic ./asm
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/uapi$
```

I was then able to redo `make` however I ran into another usage of `asm` rather than `asm-generic` in a different include directory.

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ make
make ARCH=riscv64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build M=/home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-9) 12.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Debian 12.2.0-10) 12.2.0
  CC [M]  /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/build_bug.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/container_of.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/list.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/module.h:12,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/basic_types.h:76,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/include/drv_types.h:26,
                 from /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include/linux/compiler.h:254:10: fatal error: asm/rwonce.h: No such file or directory
  254 | #include <asm/rwonce.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/scripts/Makefile.build:254: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/Makefile:1876: /home/user/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2410: modules] Error 2
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$
```

So I used the same procedure in the different include tree.

```
user@starfive:~/Documents/github/rtl88x2bu$ cd /usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include$ ls
acpi         crypto       keys   linux     memory  pcmcia  rv    sound   uapi  video
asm-generic  drm          kunit  math-emu  misc    ras     scsi  target  ufs   xen
clocksource  dt-bindings  kvm    media     net     rdma    soc   trace   vdso
user@starfive:/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-6-common/include$ sudo ln -s ./asm-generic ./asm
```

I've just run into an error due to a needed option change in the `Makefile` I'm modifying to support riscv64. However the source seems to be compiling reasonably well though with warnings. Most warnings have some connection to the size of an `int` such as cast from pointer to int.