# Help locating linux/version.h

Tags: compiling, make, c, makefile, linux-headers

I'm trying to fix an old program, Previous issues I had could be found at
[Missing modversions.h](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389245/missing-modversions-h)

When I `make` the program it gives me the following error,

```
kaodv-mod.c:22:27: fatal error: linux/version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So I ran

```
find / -name version.h
```

which returns

```
/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.2/src/vboxguest-4.3.2/vboxguest/include/VBox/version.h
/usr/include/linux/dvb/version.h
/usr/include/linux/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/config/arch/want/ipc/parse/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/xen/interface/version.h
```

This clearly proved that `linux/version.h` is present

In order to fix this, should I change

```c
#include<linux/version.h>
```

into

```
#include</usr/include/linux/version.h>
```

Or is it possible to make changes to the Makefile

P.S: [Makefile](https://github.com/erimatnor/aodv-uu/blob/master/lnx/Makefile)

Answer (score 11):

First you need to install kernel-headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If it doesn't work then try this also

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

Edited for `types.h`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/uapi/asm-generic/types.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h
```

Comment: I already have the headers installed, so created the ln
But it produces another error `/lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:23: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory` I find it very odd, why would there be an error in `/lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build/include/uapi/linux/types.h` it being a part of the linux header

Comment: @AshiqIrphan types.h file's directory is changed. It's now in include/uapi/asm-generic/. To fix your error follow the edited section

Answer (score 1):

With apt-file you can find any file Ubuntu provides:

```
$ apt-file search linux/version.h
gcc-arm-linux-androideabi: /usr/arm-linux-androideabi/include/linux/version.h
linux-headers-3.11.0-11-lowlatency: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-11-lowlatency/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
linux-headers-3.4.0-1-goldfish: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.4.0-1-goldfish/include/linux/version.h
linux-libc-dev: /usr/include/linux/version.h
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross: /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/linux/version.h
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux/version.h
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/linux/version.h
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross: /usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/include/linux/version.h
ruby1.8-dev: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux/version.h
```

From this list, linux-libc-dev looks like the most promising candidate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h* in source code tree starting from linux kernel 4.14;

Here is a way how to generate it under Ubuntu

1. Install linux headers

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
   ```
2. Go to linux headers directory

   ```
   cd /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`
   ```
3. Generate *version.h*

   ```
   sudo make include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
   ```
4. Create symbol link to generate file

   ```
   sudo ln -s $PWD/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h include/version.h
   ```